# when using jmockit, how to batch mock classes by special class and do inverse

Tags: testing, mocking, jmockit

In the spring environment using Jmockit, I usually want to test a class that needs to mock many other many classes (which this class depends on).

---

E.g:

There are now `Class1`, `Class2`, ..., `Class20`.

Class1 depends on `Class2`, `Class3`, ..., `Class20` (via spring ioc).

I want to test `Class1`, and need mocks for `Class2`, `Class3`, ..., `Class20` which is too much trouble.

How can I write only once code that can mock `Class2`, `Class3`, ..., `Class20`.

---

The function I expect is this:

```
@Mocked (excludeClasses = {Class1}) (excludeClasses expect is a variable paramter)    
@Test    
public void methodOfClass1 () {
    // test code
}
```